# Relacionar tabelas de categorias com subcategorias

Tags: php

Quero relacionar duas tabelas. Por exemplo, quando clicar num item, aparecer todos os itens relacionados a ele

```
?>
        <?php
    include "conexao.php";


$sql = "SELECT *FROM categorias ";


$resultado = pg_query($conexao, $sql);
$linhas = pg_num_rows($resultado);


      $nome_categoria = $linhas["nome_categoria"];
            $resultado.= "<option>".$nome_categoria."</option>";
    $categoria = "<select class='select_roupas'>". $resultado."</select>";

for($i = 0; $i < $linhas; $i++)
{

$registro = pg_fetch_array($resultado, $i);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM subcategorias ";
$resultado1= pg_query($conexao,$sql1);
$registro1=pg_fetch_array ($resultado1)  ;  

      $nome_subcategoria = $linhas["nome_subcategoria"];
            $resultado1.= "<option>".$nome_subcategoria."</option>";
    $subcategoria = "<select class='select_roupas'>". $resultado1."</select>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

na tabela subcategorias vc precisa armazenar o id da tabela categorias, sendo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM subcategorias WHERE categoria_id = $id_categoria;
```

desta forma irá pegar todos os resultados da tabela subcategorias onde a categoria seja a "selecionada"

Comment: Hum..Obrigada. Mas ainda assim, não está mostrando nenhum resultado. Nem das categorias.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que procure pela web sobre **Combos Aninhados**, **Combos Dinâmicos**.

Você precisará de PHP + Javascript para resolver esse tipo de situação.

> Veja esse exemplo e adapte para o seu uso:
>
> http://gilbertoalbino.com/criar-combo-dinamico-em-ajax-com-jquery-php/